# Retagging efforts

Tags: discussion, tags, retagging

I've been doing some re-tagging. Here's a bit of what I've been up to:

1. I created a few new tags, namely [magical-items](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magical-items), [magical-creatures](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magical-creatures), and [character-development](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/character-development)
2. I'm tagging questions related to the force with the [powers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/powers) tag. It seemed the most appropriate place to put it.
3. I did some general retagging as well.

I've probably done a bit more, but here's a start. Feel free to continue my work if you wish